# iOS 6: libpython2.7.a initialization import error

Tags: python, ios, embedded

Stuck on initialization Embedded Python on iOS.
I took build script from Kivy project.
It produced libpython2.7.a, Python27.zip and includes.

So, my app unpacks zip to /Documents/lib/python2.7

Trying to set up Python:

```
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                               NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
Py_SetPythonHome((char *)[docsDir UTF8String]);
Py_SetProgramName("");
Py_Initialize();
```

Falls on:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

As I understand, it cant locate Python home path.
But if I fix site by:

```
Py_NoSiteFlag=1;
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys as s\nprint(s.path)");
```

It outputs valid pathes:

```
['/var/mobile/Applications/1BC015FC-2F7A-41C0-8F3A-70A22510C3A3/Documents/lib/python27.zip', '/var/mobile/Applications/1BC015FC-2F7A-41C0-8F3A-70A22510C3A3/Documents/lib/python2.7/', '/var/mobile/Applications/1BC015FC-2F7A-41C0-8F3A-70A22510C3A3/Documents/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/var/mobile/Applications/1BC015FC-2F7A-41C0-8F3A-70A22510C3A3/Documents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/var/mobile/Applications/1BC015FC-2F7A-41C0-8F3A-70A22510C3A3/Documents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/var/mobile/Applications/1BC015FC-2F7A-41C0-8F3A-70A22510C3A3/Documents/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/var/mobile/Applications/1BC015FC-2F7A-41C0-8F3A-70A22510C3A3/Documents/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/var/mobile/Applications/1BC015FC-2F7A-41C0-8F3A-70A22510C3A3/Documents/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload']
```

But no one import works.
What I must fix to make Python correctly work with modules?

Answer (score 4):

Already fixed it by myself.
My mistakes were:
- Need to place all python /lib file in base program files as directory (not group)
- Add this directory in build phases "Upload Resources" list
- In build phase put "Upload resources" stage upper than "Compile program". Don't know why, but it helps.